# Expansion for $\cos$ at $n\theta = C + \frac{C^3}{24}h^2 + \frac{3C^5}{640}h^4 + o(h^4)$ as a polynomial in $h$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

We have $C>0, h>0$ fixed constants. And $\cos \theta = 1-\frac{h^2}{2}C^2$, for $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. Using Taylor series expansion,

$$\theta = Ch + \frac{C^3}{24}h^3 + \frac{3C^5}{640}h^5 + o(h^5).$$
Now taking $n=1/h$, we have 
$$n\theta = C + \frac{C^3}{24}h^2 + \frac{3C^5}{640}h^4 + o(h^4).$$

Then, we get

$$\cos(n\theta) = \cos C - \frac{C^3}{24} \sin Ch^2 - \frac{27\sin C + 5C \cos C}{5760} C^5h^4 + o(h^4).$$

How do we get this last expansion for $\cos (n\theta)$? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that 
$$ n\theta = C + D ,\quad D := \frac{C^3}{24}h^2 + \frac{3C^5}{640}h^4 + O(h^6). $$
Using the addition formula $\ \cos(x+y) = \cos x \cos y  - \sin x \sin y  \ $
we get the equation
$$ \cos n\theta  = \cos C \cos D  - \sin C \sin D . $$
Now $\ \cos D  = 1 - \frac{C^6}{1152}h^4 + O(h)^6 \ $ and 
$\ \sin D  = \frac{C^3}{24}h^2 + \frac{3C^5}{640}h^4 + O(h)^6. \ $
Substituting we get
$$ \cos n\theta  = \cos C \Big( 1 - \frac{C^6}{1152}h^4 + O(h)^6 \Big)
  - \sin C  \Big(\frac{C^3}{24}h^2 + \frac{3C^5}{640}h^4 + O(h)^6 \Big)  $$
and your result follows.